# MvvmCross: How to pass paramters to view models with v3?

Tags: mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I am trying to pass a paramter to my ViewModel during my ShowViewModel call and am having trouble.  All of the example seem to be old as they use RequestNavigate which doesn't exist anymore in v3??  When I try to build up my parameter MvxBundle, I am not sure what to put inside such that the view model gets constructed properly by the IOC.  I can always handle this myself inside my custom ViewModelLocator, but I thought the system would do it for me using the paramterBundle argument of ShowViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

The redesign for viewmodel life cycle was discussed [here](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html)

Afaik, the only thing that changed since then was the introduction of ShowViewModel instead of RequestNavigate

There's an N+1 video about navigation on [this page](http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/04/n5-some-first-icommands-and-multiple.html)

There's a navigation demo app [here](https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/tree/master/Navigation)

Comment: I hate magic methods. they can not be discovered without googling or reading the doc. I'm talking about `public void Init(long memberId)`

Comment: But great article about viewmodel lifecycle. Should be first in the wiki.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was trying to accept the parameters in the constructor of my view model instead of relying on the InitFromBundle method.  Watching the Collect-A-Bull series helped on this one.