# Open View for Selected ViewModel

Tags: xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm struggling to find the right way to do this. I have a `MyCollectionViewModel` which contains an observable collections of `MyViewModel`. I have this bound to a view `MyCollectionView` with the selection of an item bound back to a command in `MyCollectionViewModel` called `OpenMyViewCommand`. So far so good:

```
    private MvxCommand<MyViewModel> _openMyViewCommand;
    public ICommand OpenMyViewCommand
    {
        get {
            _openMyViewCommand= _openMyViewCommand?? new MvxCommand<MyViewModel>(OpenMyView);
            return _openSubViewCommand;
        }
    }
```

Now when I touch one of the items on my list view it will fire the command and call the method `OpenMyView` passing the selected `MyViewModel` to the method. Now the problem is that no matter what I try, I can seem to get `ShowViewModel` to display the view for the selected model. I've tried various things, but intuitively, I would have expected something really simple like this to work:

```
    private void OpenMyView(MyViewModel item) {
                ShowViewModel<MyViewModel > (item);
    }
```

But, of course, it doesn't. I get errors that look like this:

```
013-06-10 10:46:05.849 MyAppIPhoneUI[51198:c07] mvx: Warning:   5.83 Problem creating viewModel of type MyViewModel - problem MvxException: Failed to resolve parameter for parameter model of type MyModel when creating MyApp.Core.MyViewModel
at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.GetIoCParameterValues (System.Type type, System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo firstConstructor) [0x00042] in /MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:377 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.IoC.MvxSimpleIoCContainer.IoCConstruct (System.Type type) [0x00030] in /MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/IoC/MvxSimpleIoCContainer.cs:266 
at Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.IocConstruct (System.Type t) [0x00006] in /MvvmCross-3/CrossCore/Cirrious.CrossCore/Mvx.cs:115 
at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.TryLoad (System.Type viewModelType, IMvxBundle parameterValues, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModel& viewModel) [0x00004] in /MvvmCross-3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross/ViewModels/MvxDefaultViewModelLocator.cs:27 

013-06-10 10:24:11.330 MyAppIPhoneUI[50878:c07] mvx: Warning:   6.87 Exception masked MvxException: Failed to load ViewModel for type MyApp.Core.MyViewModel from locator MvxDefaultViewModelLocator
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelLoader.LoadViewModel (Cirrious.MvvmCross.ViewModels.MvxViewModelRequest request, IMvxBundle savedState, IMvxViewModelLocator viewModelLocator) [0x00023] in /MvxViewModelLoader.cs:46
```

Any idea what's going on here? I have a `MyView` class that inherits from MvxViewController, but it doesn't get loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation is done via things like Android `Intent`s and WindowsPhone `Uri`s - so it has to be done via serializable types - see:

- [Custom types in Navigation parameters in v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524236/custom-types-in-navigation-parameters-in-v3)
- [MvvmCross: How to pass paramters to view models with v3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16743631/mvvmcross-how-to-pass-paramters-to-view-models-with-v3)
- http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/03/v3-new-viewmodel-lifecycle.html

Try changing your code to something like:

```
  ShowViewModel<MyViewModel>(new { id = item.Id });
```

with a receiving `MyViewModel` like:

```
  public void Init(int id)
  {
     MyItem = myItemLookupService.Lookup(id);      
  }
```

Also, please bear in mind that you have very little control over the lifecycle of your app - it could get 'tombstoned' at any moment. So don't expect that just because `MyViewModel` receives a navigation request, then the item for that request will always be in memory - you may need to create or fetch it all over again.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I've redone it similar to the collect-a-bull part 4 and it seems to work, but it seems like a long way around. But I guess your point about lifecycle is something I need to read up on some more.